# how to use standardization / standardscaler() for train and test?

Tags: cross-validation, feature-scaling

At the moment I perform the following:

```
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
prepare_data = Pipeline(estimators)

n_splits = 5
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = n_splits)

for train_index, val_index in tscv.split(df_train):
    X_train, X_val = prepare_data.fit_transform(df_train[train_index]), prepare_data.fit_transform(df_train[val_index])

X_test = prepare_data.fit_transform(df_test)
```

Now I would like to know if this is correct. My concern is that `X_train` and `X_test` are transformed separately. While in the first instance I thought this is how it should be I'm about to change my mind as I think I have to use the `mean` and `std` of the train set to use within the test set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way (see 'Elements of Statistical Learning', chapter 'The Wrong and Right Way to Do Cross-validation') is to calculate the mean and the standard deviation of the values in the training set and then apply them for standardizing **both** the training and testing sets.

The idea behind this is to prevent data leakage from the testing to the training set because the aim of model validation is to subject the testing data to the same conditions as the data used for the model training.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Can you also add how I do that? :) Or let's say, how do I get the mean and sd of the training set and apply it to another set?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using scikit-learn...

What you have to do is to *fit* the pipeline with *X_train* and for *X_test* only tranform.

With the **fit** method you will compute the mean and std. dev. on the given data (*X_train*) and with the **transform** you apply the transformation with these computed values to a given dataset.

The problem is that in scikit-learn, there is no isolated **transform** method, it is embbeded in the **predict** method, that eventually applies all transformations and gives the predictions of the last estimator of the PipeLine.

In this post, how to apply only transformations is explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469633/how-to-transform-items-using-sklearn-pipeline

Comment: Thanks a lot! So does this mean I have to calculate mean and std on my own for the training set and apply these to the test set? I'm just thinking about to add this obvious method to scikit but on the other side I think there is a reason why it is not already?!

Comment: Scikit does it for you: **fit** method calculates mean and std on whichever the dataset you choose, and **transform** applies the transofrmation with the computed values by the **fit**. So, if you call **estimator1.fit_transform(_x\_train_)**  you compute mean and std on _x_train_(and store them)  and standarize _x\_train_. When you call**estimator1.transform(_x\_val_)** you only apply the standarization without re-computing the paramaters. **NOTE**: transform method does not exist isolated in scikit-learn

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Alright, thank you very much!